# Begin and End Arrow Types in Excel Charts

Tags: excel, charts

[image: Phasor Diagram]

I needed a phasor diagram and I made one with a scatter chart. So here is my problem.

The "begin arrow type" is set to none, the "end arrow type" is set to triangle. There are many excel workbooks like this and I can't go through each and everyone to fix this. Not sure why, but for some of these I have to set the "begin arrow type" to triangle and the "end arrow type" to none so that the vector arrows are outward instead of inward. I can't find logical steps to change this property via VBA either. Can anyone tell me why this happens? Here are my chart series:

```
=SERIES(Sheet1!$A$2,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$2,Sheet1!$D$2:$E$2,1)
=SERIES(Sheet1!$A$3,Sheet1!$B$3:$C$3,Sheet1!$D$3:$E$3,2)
=SERIES(Sheet1!$A$4,Sheet1!$B$4:$C$4,Sheet1!$D$4:$E$4,3)
=SERIES(Sheet1!$A$5,Sheet1!$B$5:$C$5,Sheet1!$D$5:$E$5,4)
=SERIES(Sheet1!$A$6,Sheet1!$B$6:$C$6,Sheet1!$D$6:$E$6,6)
```

Comment: Did you try the macro recorder?

Comment: Not sure what is that got to do with anything. I don't know why some values make the head of arrow go inward. I don't have a logic yet to write a macro. Need the logic.

Comment: You said that you can't find a way to change these properties with VBA, with the macro recorder you can discover where those properties are located in the Excel object model (e.g. calls such as `s.Format.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle` where `s` is a series object). The arrows point in the order in which the points appear in a series. If some of them point the wrong way -- you need to change the order in which the points appear in the data or swap the roles of `BeginArrowheadStyle` and `EndArrowheadStyle`. Do all of the data series consist of 2 points?

Comment: Where is the series number 5? It seems odd, that the numeration (last Digit of the the formula before the `)`) of your 5 series goes up to 6 with the 5 missing. Especially, as there are only 5 series.

Comment: @Mister832 series 5 is a blank series, go figure.

Comment: Have you tried deleting series 5?

Comment: @JohnColeman I have the code to change the beginning or the end of arrows, no problem. What I cant figure out is how for some of these series, it has to be on the beginning and on some of the series it has to be on end of it. Based on what logic. If what you say -3<-1 is fine, so what about -1.6>-2.1 which is fine as well and contrary to this logic?

Comment: @Mister832, no, I really didn't care about that. I doubt that is what messes the direction of arrows which is my main concern.

Comment: I recreated you Chart, an it works fine, with all the arrows pointing outwards. So I think, this series 5 is the Problem, as it is the only difference. Could you Elaborate on what an empty series is, so i can recreate it myself?

Comment: As far as I understood it, columns b + d are starting Point of the arrow (x, y) and columns c + e are the end Points of the arrow. So i you set `EndArrowheadStyle`, the arrow head should appear near the coordinates given by column c + e. The easy guess would be, that the series values are mix up, but given the formulas provided, they are not.

Comment: @Mister832, I left the file at work. I remember when I chose data selection for the chart, there was a blank series there, but I didn't pay much attention to it. I also recreated the file now and it works fine. Not sure what sort of voodoo was at work. :/

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide this sheet in a file?

Comment: Sure, in three or four days when I have access to my work computer again. I think it was acting up because I made it while it was saved as a 2003 compatible file. I changed it to a .xlsx file and it stopped acting up.

Comment: @Mister832 Here you go, this is the magic file. :p https://clicknupload.link/2al9al79o3z8

Comment: One funny thing: I changed the chart type to "interpolated lines with datapoints". It looked exactly the same, with the arrows pointing all in the same direction. However, they point away from the origin

Comment: @Mister832 Changing it to scatter with smooth lines fixes it too. Anyway, thank you, it was a great help back then, I really thought there must be some sort of rule about these arrows that I don't know, but it seems the chart was somehow corrupted. Once I made a new chart and copied from that in xlsx format, everything went fine.